# Doubt in basics of inequalities

Tags: inequality

While solving a problem I encountered with this
$ 4m(4m-1) \leq 0 $
Solving this one gets the solution $ 0 \leq m \leq 1/4 $
Now, if the inequation is multiplied with -1 on both sides we get
$ 4m(1-4m) \geq 0 $
Solving this, we get $ m \leq 0 $ or $m \geq 1/4 $
Individually the solutions are correct but the inequalities are the same. So, what is wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Double check your second inequality’s  solutions. Individually not correct.

Comment: How did you get the last inequalities?

Comment: You solved the second set of inequalities wrong. You should again get $m\leq\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the multiplication of two terms, and you are looking for an inequality with zero, you can use the basics of when the product of two numbers is positive, negative, or zero.

In the first inequality, you have:

$$4m(4m-1) \le 0$$

So, you are looking for one of these factors to be greater than or equal to zero and the other to be less than or equal to zero. Thus, you need:

$$4m\ge 0 \text{ and } 4m-1 \le 0$$

or

$$4m\le 0 \text{ and } 4m-1 \ge 0$$

The first one breaks down to $m\ge 0\text{ and }m\le \dfrac{1}{4}$.

The second breaks down to $m\le 0 \text{ and } m\ge \dfrac{1}{4}$. In order for one factor to be positive and the other negative, we need both inequalities to be satisfied. Note the and between the inequalities. There are no numbers $m$ that satisfy both of these inequalities, so we reject this.

This gives the $0\le m \le \dfrac{1}{4}$ that you already got.

Next, we consider the second inequality:

$$4m(1-4m)\ge 0$$

You need both factors at least zero or both factors at most zero.

$$4m\ge 0\text{ and }1-4m \ge 0$$

or

$$4m\le 0\text{ and } 1-4m \le 0$$

The first inequality gives $0\le m \le \dfrac{1}{4}$.

The second inequality gives $m\le 0\text{ and }\dfrac{1}{4}\le m$. There are no values of $m$ that satisfy both inequalities. So we wind up with the same final solution.

Answer (score 1):

You misapplied the theorem on quadratic inequalities. Namely, it says that

> A quadratic polynomial has the sign of its leading  coefficient outside of the interval of its roots, and the opposite sign  between these roots, if any.

What you did was that, multiplying both side by $-1$, you also changed the sign of the leading coefficient from `+` to `–`.